# IBM Worklight plugin on Eclipse Juno disppeared

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I downloaded eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32 and installed IBM Worklight as a plugin. It worked well for almost 2 months (don't remember exactly how many days). But it disappeared all of a sudden. Now I don't see any work light related options in eclipse. Any idea what could be reason ? & How to install it again ?

Thanks..Johnson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's strange indeed, but easiest solution would be to extract a fresh copy of Eclipse, install Worklight into it and import your existing Worklight project from the workspace of the previous Eclipse installation.

Comment: Specifically, a newer version than Juno (which is now two years old).

Comment: Idan, Thanks for your reply. I have extracted a fresh copy of eclipse and installed work light plugin. I can see that its installed (I can see it in Help-Installation Details-Installed Software tab) But for some reason, I am not able to see any options related work light. Please help!!

Comment: You are either using an incorrect version of Eclipse or maybe your Worklight installation is corrupt. Download Eclipse Java EE Kepler and install Worklight again

Comment: I am now using Eclipse Kepler with worklight 6.1.0.1 on it. I think the issue was due to using incorrect combination of eclipse version with worklight. Now its resolved.